# Moving bulk files from one external disk to other does nothing

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, external-hard-drive, file-transfer, copy-paste

I am trying to move all my music (~700GB) from one external hard drive to another one. While in the past, I used to do that with just dragging and dropping the files, now it does nothing at all. Not even displaying a message for the reason it's not doing it.

No move dialog (speed, estimated time, etc.) and no error either.

The subfolders can be copied if done few at a time.

I've seen a few solutions using command prompt to copy the files or using other software, but I want to do this using only Windows explorer, as I used to do in the past.

Note that this happens on both my Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate PC and my Windows 8.1 64-bit Enterprise PC.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: if you have a virus scanner, try disabling it for the copy.  Virus scanners can seriously bog down large file transfers.

Comment: @Keltari: I already did that but to no avail, thanks for the advice anyway!

Answer (score 1):

There is not a file size limit on copying/pasting in Win7, but larger operations - yours definitely qualifies - can lead to very slow response times, especially on slower or dated machines. You may try just waiting a minute and checking to see if the copy process appears in the task manager.  If you're sure something bigger than that is the culprit, I would give TeraCopy a try.  I know it's not exactly what you ordered, but to me it's the next logical step if you want to avoid the command line.

TeraCopy: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeraCopy

TeraCopy also features native context menu integration, so you can right click a file or directory and copy with it similarly to how you would with Explorer.  The caveat is that dragging and dropping won't trigger TeraCopy, just Explorer.

Comment: You have at least attempted to explain how this answers the author's question so I have removed my other comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the file name is too long and Windows can't deal with it, sometimes it doesn't display error messages if that's the issue. In OS's perspective the file name includes the whole path of the file location. A file named 1.jpg is actually seen as C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\1.jpg. Are you trying to copy the files to a sub folder or to the root directory of the destination drive?  Try copying to the root directory or shorten the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to copy instead of move, then delete the source folder.

Windows Copy uses (or at least used to use) System Swap File for operations like that. So copying large amount of data may be SLOOOOOOW... Especially when you do something else besides this

I personally use Total Commander to do copying like you have to do. It offers mode bypassing windows mechanism and other functions I find highly useful.

Are both external drives the same? Maybe new one is formatted as some uncommon FAT32 variant? If you have somewhere long path (as Techpumpkin_WD suggests) there may be an issue.

Windows usually first calculates data amount, then commits to copy. This can take long time as well.